# Physical interpretation of an infinite eigenvalue

Tags: energy, operators, electrons, eigenvalue, intuition

First, I am a mathematician with some basic knowledge in quantum mechanics, so I should be able to understand a few details, but I am more looking for a physical intuition of my problem. I am working on the following theorem:

*We look at the boundary-value problem {$Lu=\lambda u$ in $U$, $u=0$ on $\partial U$}, for $L$ a symmetric elliptic operator, and $U$ an open, bounded set. Then, if we repeat each eigenvalue according to its (finite) multiplicity, we have $0<\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 \leq \ldots$ and $\lambda_k \rightarrow \infty$.*

My problem is that I am struggling to picture how this physically works. Let us take the example of an electron. Would this theorem mean that an electron might possibly have an infinite number of energy levels, and thus that it might actually have an infinite amount of energy?  I thought it was not practically possible.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g

Comment: Thank you for this video on the construction of eigenvalues but that is not what I asked..

Comment: Yes, there is no upper bound on the energy of a quantum system.

Comment: But is this true that in order for the electron to go to an infinite energy level, we should also provide it an infinite amount of energy, so it is only theoretical?

Comment: @Spida I guess what you are asking is not specifically quantum. The eigenvalues represent the *possible* eigenenergy state for the electron, such that it could *conceptually* occupy these. In classical Newtonian mechanics the physical laws also do not provide you any "in principle" limit to the energy a particle can have. A free classical particle in principle have an infinite velocity. The constraint on its energy would come from external arguments, outside from the description of this physical system.

Comment: @StarBucK that is really helpful, thank you!

Comment: "Would this theorem mean that an electron might possibly have an infinite number of energy levels, " This is the missconception, it is not the electron that has energy levels, but the atom( or more than one particle in a potential )

Comment: @annav if by energy levels you think about electronic structure I agree. However an electron can have different Kinetic energies (which would be a continuum set in free space). I guess OP question is relatively general and does not necessarily apply in your case. You can have energies eigenvalue without any potential.

Comment: I ask to consider that the field of the electron is considered to be continuous and therefore infinite. This concept is in the world because the field is treated as structureless (not quantized). If we would postulate a model of the electric field, we would realize that we need a field quantum (no structure without particle). If we postulate a quantum, this has to have a defined energy value. But with that the field of the electron is no longer infinite. What doesn't bother at all, because in fact the influence of two electrons on each other is no longer detectable with increasing distance. …

Comment: … But it probably does not lead any more to calculations whose result are infinite energies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An electron may have an infinite number of eigenvalues but no eigenvalue is infinite. In other words you can continue to give an electron more energy as long as you have energy to give to it (you will never reach a point where electron simply cannot have more energy) but there is no state in which the electron has an infinite energy.

Obviously this is based on a particular model. We have only been able to test this up to a finite energy, e.g. the LHC has achieved energies of a few TeVs.

Comment: You are contributing to the miss conception of the OP. An electron by itself does not have energy levels, it needs to be in an interaction with other particles in a bound state for energy levels for the system to exist. The LHC has nothing to do with bound states.

Comment: The  energy of LHC beam particles are on a continuum about the beam energy.